# Dynamic DNS w/ DSL ISP behind a multi-WAN router? Other ISP is behind CGNAT

Tags: networking, router, dns, dd-wrt

I'm trying to make *some* of the services on a Linux server accessible outside my LAN.  I have a Perforce depot I want a couple other people to have access to (with ssl & login credentials). I have two ISPs right now - CenturyLink DSL, and Starlink.  My plan was to put both on a multi-WAN / load balancing router, and then set up dynamic DNS on the CenturyLink router (it can do that natively), so that it would have a fixed domain name.  I have to use the CenturyLink router for two reasons: Starlink has signal drops (I live in the trees), and the whole Starlink network is on a CGNAT, so I can't use dynamic DNS with it instead of CenturyLink.

Would the dynamic DNS name from the CenturyLink router and inbound traffic to it still resolve correctly from behind a multi-WAN router, and would outbound traffic prefer the better Starlink connection except when it's dropped for a few seconds?

I have a spare Netgear R8000 with dd-wrt on it that I can use, either behind a load-balancing router or as one (if it can do that).  The Starlink ethernet adapter is coming ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic DNS does not care about the router save that it needs to have a routable IP on the wan interface.

You almost certainly can't have packets going in to the Centurylink interface and out Starnet as it will likely not work with reverse path filtering, let alone CGNAT.

Have you considered a VPN service to deliver a static IP address directly to your network instead? In that way, if you can tackle failover/failback you can have the connection choose the better route.  (*by VPN I mean using a service that provides a static IP across a vpn tunnel - this is a common service but not quite the same as privacy related vpn's, although they can use the same software and many vpn providers offer both services)

Comment: I'm open to configuring it however it needs to work.  I have a NordVPN subscription, would that work?

Comment: If you are using NordVPN you can apparently just by their "Dedicated IP" addon -  https://nordvpn.com/features/dedicated-ip/ - Note that using a Dedicated IP can negate many of the anonymity benefits of a VPN if you are using NordVPN for that purpose (because all your traffic is associated with the static IP address)